# FullCalendar - week view events display vertical order

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is it possible to show the events one below the other like the image?[i want view week with events vertical order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASc5r.png)

sorry my English is not perfet

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible without editing the source code of fullcalendar.

The best you can do is set eventOverlap: false so that users at least cannot drag and drop the events to have the same time.

You can also try fullcalendar's scheduler plugin which will do almost the same. Search the documentation for vertical resources layout.