# Fullcalendar.js Customizing render events. Rendering Events in Vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Recently i needed to render events in fullcalendar.js in Vertical direction.

My solution is something like it for who needs it and dont mind to use a "gambiarra":

```
 eventRender: function(event, element) {
                  element[0].setAttribute("dia",event.data);
                  element[0].setAttribute("hora",event.hora);

    },eventAfterAllRender: function(event, element) 
        { organizacalendario() },
            eventAfterRender: function(event, element) 
        { 
            var existe = 0;
                $(arrayorder).each(function(index,value)
                {
                    if ( event.hora == value)
                    { 
                        existe = 1;
                        return;
                    }

                  });
                if ( existe == 0 )
                { 
                  arrayorder.push(event.hora);
                }   

            arrayorder.sort(); }

    function organizacalendario()
    {

        $(arrayorder).each(function(index,horaelemento)
        {

            //renderiza os elementos da hora definida
           $("#calendar").find(".fc-time-grid-event").each(function(ordem,element)
           {
               $(element).css("left","");
               $(element).css("right","");
               $(element).css("bottom","");
              if ( $(element).attr("hora") == horaelemento && $(element).css("z-index") > 1  )
              {
                   if ( horaelemento.substring(3,5) <= 29 && $(element).attr("data") == $(previous).attr("data")  )
                   {   
                       // aumenta o fc-axis para suportar +  1 evento
                       $(".fc-slats").find("span:contains('"+horaelemento.substring(0,2)+"')").parent("td").parent("tr").css("height", Number($(".fc-slats").find("span:contains('"+horaelemento.substring(0,2)+"')").parent("td").parent("tr").css("height").replace("px","")) + Number($(element).css("height").replace("px","")));

                   }else if ( horaelemento.substring(3,5) >= 30 && $(element).attr("data") == $(previous).attr("data")  )
                   {   
                       // aumenta o fc-axis para suportar +  1 evento
                       $(".fc-slats").find("span:contains('"+horaelemento.substring(0,2)+"')").parent("td").parent("tr").next("tr").css("height", Number($(".fc-slats").find("span:contains('"+horaelemento.substring(0,2)+"')").parent("td").parent("tr").next("tr").css("height").replace("px","")) + Number($(element).css("height").replace("px","")));

                   }



                   //seta top de acordo com height anteriro
                   $(element).css("top",Number($(previous).css("top").replace("px","")) + Number($(previous).css("height").replace("px","")))


              }
              else if ( $(element).attr("hora") == horaelemento )
              {
                  if ( horaelemento.substring(3,5) <= 29 )
                  {
                     $(this).css("top",$(".fc-slats").find("span:contains('"+horaelemento.substring(0,2)+"')").parent("td").parent("tr")[0].offsetTop)
                  }else
                  {
                     $(this).css("top",$(".fc-slats").find("span:contains('"+horaelemento.substring(0,2)+"')").parent("td").parent("tr").next("tr")[0].offsetTop)
                  }

              }

              $(".fc-time-grid-container").css("height",$(".fc-slats").css("height")); 
               $("#area_container").css("background","");
               previous = this;
           })
        })
    }
```

but, the question is.. does somebody developed some change in fullcalendar.js to make it happens without "gambiarras"? i try to do all in eventafterrender but seems like fullcalendar renders ordered by different parameters then json string. if somebody can shows me a most elegant solution i will be glad in positive.. thanks

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37699119/2783654), maybe the fullcalendar scheduler plugin would do the job.